# How to parameterize the Branch name and load the shared library implicitly

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-cli

I want to parameterize the Branch name and load the shared library implicitly.

@Library('my-shared-library/$BRANCH_NAME') _

I am getting the following error message.

'''
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: @Library value ‘my-shared-library@$BRANCH_NAME’ was not a constant; did you mean to use the ‘library’ step instead?

1 error

```
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
```

'''

Is there any way I can pass the parameter only in the shared library implicitly?

Comment: Replace the single quote with double quotes. I think your Parms are not substituted

Answer (score 1):

There are two options for loading [Shared Libraries](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/), Static loading that occurs before the pipeline script is executed using the `@Library` keyword, and dynamic loading using the `library`.
While is static loading you can't use parameters, in dynamic loading you can do so:

> As of version 2.7 of the Pipeline: Shared Groovy Libraries plugin, there is a new option for loading (non-implicit) libraries in a script: a library step that loads a library dynamically, at any time during the build.

```
library 'my-shared-library'
```

Regarding versions in dynamic libraries:

> When using the library step you may also specify a version:
> `library 'my-shared-library@master'`.
> Since this is a regular step, that version could be computed rather than a
> constant as with the annotation;
> For example:
> `library "my-shared-library@$BRANCH_NAME"`

Comment: Note that the library step may not be used to override the version of an implicitly loaded library. It is already loaded by the time the script starts, and a library of a given name may not be loaded twice. So If you have a global library that is implicitly loaded you cannot specify the version dynamically.
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#library-versions